# Getting index number of list item using Python?

Tags: python

this gives me a list of all 55 layers in my mxd

```
import arcpy 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layer")[0] 
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    print lyr.name
```

What I want to do is get the index number of a specific layer.  For example, I want to look for the layer named 'Water' and I want the script to tell me "Water' is at position 50, so I know to look for it at the bottom on the TOC.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
import arcpy 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layer")[0] 
for i,lyr in enumerate(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)):
    print "Layer {0}: {1}".format(i, lyr.name)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the **index()** method:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layer")[0]
lyrNameList = []
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
    lyrNameList.append(lyr.name)
print lyrNameList.index("Land Use")
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> for index,y in enumerate(x):
...     print index,y
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Or from your snippet:

```
for i,lyr in enumerate(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)):
    print i,lyr.name
```

Comment: Enumerate pointed me in the right direction.  I just had to add a conditional if statement to do what I wanted to do  - find the position of a specific layer... if lyr.name == "Land Use": before the print line.